# when i push the code into bitbucket then jenkins job can't build automatically

Tags: jenkins, automation, bitbucket, webhooks

When I push the code into Bitbucket then Jenkins job can't build automatically. I can build manually. I configure the jenkins job with Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket this option. But it doesn't work. Help me..

my setup

I create new job in pipeline style

1. Build Triggers
       Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket
   i select this option
2. Pipeline
      pipeline script from SCM 
      Git repository
      Script path : Jenkinsfile

i am using this setup in my jenkins job..
 My system is Ubuntu 18.04 studio

I can get the all details and logs but i need anutomatically build the jenkins job.

Comment: did you setup a webhook trigger in bitbucket?

Comment: @Stefano yes , i setup the webhook trigger in bitbucket

Comment: then I'd suggest to check the jenkins logs to verify that the webhooks are properly fetched

Comment: i can get the all details after i push the code into server.. but the think is i can't get automatically.. When i press the build now button and then the jenkins job build.. That is my issue

Comment: yep, it sounds like the webhook is not correctly understood by jenkins. So check the jenkins logs to verify if there are errors in converting the webhook payload. BTW, what version of BitBucket are you using? Server or cloud?